# I have query to retrieve all posts in wordpress but how can i check the condition for post meta_key =“develop” and meta_value='anything'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

```
SELECT DISTINCT date(p.post_date) as post_date
FROM $wpdb->posts p
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE p.post_status='publish'
    AND p.post_type IN ('%s')
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

Here it reads all dates of the posts. My problem is that query should exclude the posts which has meta_value(it can be anything) of which meta_key="develop" . How can i write the query for that ?

I feel it will be in this form for wp_query

```
$args[ 'meta_query' ]= array (

        'relation'= >' AND ',

                array (
                        'key' = > 'respect' 
                ),
                array (
                        'key' => 'develop',
                        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'

                )
            ); 
   $query = new Wp_query($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to get all posts that don't have a meta key equal to "develop"?

You could do this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'meta_key' => 'develop',
    'meta_compare' => 'NOT EXISTS' 
) );
```

Also, see this note from the Codex if you're using a version of Wordpress less than 3.9:

"(Note: Due to bug #23268, value is required for NOT EXISTS comparisons to work correctly prior to 3.9. You must supply some string for the value parameter. An empty string or NULL will NOT work. However, any other string will do the trick and will NOT show up in your SQL when using NOT EXISTS. Need inspiration? How about 'bug #23268'.)"

Comment: i am trying to exclude the posts which are having meta_value(it can be any value) for meta_key ="develop". I mean if the meta_value of meta_key develop is set it should exclude.

Comment: it should read all other posts which may have other meta keys also how can i write that in sql query